# Android Connectivity change intent filter

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have added `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` action to my intent filter. BroadcastReceiver's `onReceive()` is fired when there is a change in Wi-fi status or mobile data status. I need to determine if this change was due to wifi or mobile data.

Or is there any intent filter just for the case if Mobile Data is turned off?

Answer (score 0):

In a Brief :

in you onReceive() function :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context,final Intent intent) {

    ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();

// Use netInfo here : 
// netInfo.getType()
// netInfo.getTypeName()
// netInfo.isConnected()
// ...

}
```

You are now able to know if the changes come from Wifi or Mobile data, and if it's connected or not

More information : http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html